# How to check equivalent of randomly generated alphabets?

Tags: visual-c++, random, g++, srand

```
//This code gives randomly generated alphabets and if equal will
//cout the alphabet which is equal  
1 #include <iostream>
2 #include <cstdlib>
3 #include <ctime>
4 using namespace std;
5 int main()
6 {
7 int a;
8 char array[10];
9 srand (time(0));
10 for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
11 {
12 a=rand() %26;
13 a=a+97;
14 array[i]=char(a);
15 }
16 for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
17 {
18 for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
19     {
20     if (array [i]==array [j]);
21     {
22     cout <<array[i] <<" " <<array[j];//if alphabet 'c' is at indecis 2,5,8
                                       //then output should be like that of
                                       // only 22 no statement but actually it does
                                       // not give this answer but gives wrong output
                                       //c c
                                       //c c
                                       //c c 

23      }
24          cout << endl;
25     }
26 }
27 return 0;
28 } //program end
```

My question is how to check that randomly generated alphabets are equal e.g in 22 number line it should give output of equal alphabets if they are equal but it does not give equal alphabets what wrong in this code mention the wrong statement or help me how will i get right answer

Actually i want to make a program that should tell me how many times a single generated alphabet comes in an array

Comment: Please add sample input with expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: Which statement you can't understand

Comment: I want to make a progaram that tell me which alphabet come in an array how many times?

Comment: Oh, so you get "c c c c" instead of "2 5 8"?

Comment: read again i have made some modification

Comment: a) [`rand`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) is a very poor random number generator, you're in C++ use the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header and the random number generators within. b) Your question seems to indicate that you are expecting an alleged random number generator to give the same result twice; that is contrary to the desired behavior of a random number generator. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: No.Mgetz dear A C++ program that declares Character type array of size 10,then populates the array with random alphabets (a~z) and then display the most occurred element from the randomly populated unsorted array.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you're looking for something that does this:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>


int main(){
   ::std::vector<char> letters(10);
   ::std::vector<char> unique;
   ::std::random_device rd;
   ::std::mt19937 mt(rd());
   ::std::uniform_int_distribution<char> dis('a', 'z');
   auto random = ::std::bind(dis, mt);

   // fill the vector with random letters
   for(char & l : letters){
       l = random();
   }

   int max_count = 0;
   char appeared_most = ' ';

   // get a vector of all the unique values
   ::std::unique_copy(letters.cbegin(), letters.cend(), ::std::back_inserter(unique));

   // find the first value to appear most if two values appear equally
   // the first will be chosen
   for(const char & l : unique){
       int count = ::std::count(letters.cbegin(), letters.cend(), l);
       if(count > max_count){
           max_count = count;
           appeared_most = l;
       }
   }
   ::std::cout << appeared_most << " " << max_count ;
}
```

I have a working sample here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53c953576e0db756